# Call function on mainpage from frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't call function on owner page from frame.

This code from Jsfiddle shows the problem:

**Mainpage (frame owner)**:

Button frame-opener:

```
<a href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/HappyCougar/f9e1v1ck/8/show/light/" onclick="var frame = window.open(this.href, 'frame','width=1000,height=825px,toolbar=1,location=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');frame.focus(); return false;">Open Window</a>
```

Function what must calling:

```
function simple_function() {
  $("b").text("WORK!");
}
```

**Frame:**

Try to call function:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    window.opener.$('body').append("<script type='text\/javascript'>simple_function();<\/script>");
});
```

return on frame

> simple_function is not defined

and nothing on Mainpage

Whats problem?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/HappyCougar/p7dxeznc/1/show/light/ - Simple mainpage
https://fiddle.jshell.net/HappyCougar/f9e1v1ck/8/show/light/ - Simple frame

Comment: If you want the content document of an iframe it's like: `var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow, iframeDoc = iframeWindow.document;`. Of course, you must have CORS access.

Comment: @PHPglue Hmm... Problem, $(parent.document.body) -  return frame body not parent body.

https://fiddle.jshell.net//p7dxeznc/4/show/light/
https://fiddle.jshell.net/f9e1v1ck/11/show/light/

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with frames, you are talking about windows. Why don't you call the function directly from the opened window like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.opener.simple_function();
</script>
```

Comment: window.opener.simple_function is not a function